Prove the inequality $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \ge 4$
(Michael Rozenberg) Let a, b, c, d be positive real numbers such that $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 +d^2 = 4$. Show that $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \ge 4$.
This question is from the book "Basics of Olympiad Inequalities" in the chapter about Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so I'm sure that it has something to do with this problem.
The thing is that applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality blindly doesn't gives this:
$\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \ge a + b + c + d$, therefore I cannot substitute given equality. I've also tried AM-GM, different combinations of sums of given fractions. I've also tried rearrangement inequality but this one doesn't give much information too.
Thanks in advance, I've been struggling for an hour already :)

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hello, thanks for the answer. I've edited my question, is it better now?

See this

This question is similar to: How do I show that $\frac {a^2}b + \frac {b^2}c + \frac {c^2}d + \frac {d^2}a \ge 4$ for $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 4$?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found from a comment in Calvin's linked question.
